# Keras/Tensorflow: Find out which initializer was used for a model variable

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to find the initializer which was used for a trained model when only this trained model is given (saved by model.save). I cannot look it up in the code because I tested several initializers and I have one model with a particular good performance and I want to find out its parameters, also the activation functions used would be interesting.

Comment: Please provide more information such as `tensorflow` version, model definition code, model save code for others to answer your question better

Comment: tf version 2.9.0, model.save was used where model is the trained model and a minimal example would be ``model = keras.Sequential(
    [
        layers.Dense(2, activation="relu" ,kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform'),
        layers.Dense(3, activation="relu", kernel_initializer='tf.keras.initializers.RandomNormal(mean=0., stddev=1.)'),
        layers.Dense(4, name="layer3"),
    ]
)``

Comment: Hi @Philipp123! You can use [model.summary](https://www.tensorflow.org/js/guide/models_and_layers#model_summary) to see its parameters and activation function.  For visual view , You can put the model in [Netron web app](https://netron.app/).